# Integral $\int_0^1 \left(1- \left(1-y^{1/c}\right)^{1/b}\right)^{1/a}dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I desire to obtain the value of

$$\int_0^1 \left(1- \left(1-y^{1/c}\right)^{1/b}\right)^{1/a}dy$$

I tried online solvers like Wolfram Alpha and Symbolab, but they couldn't solve it.

How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please take the time to write your problem here

Comment: Why should we be able to solve this?

Comment: I have edited your question. Now a question of mine, besides asking to WA and asking us, what have you tried **by yourself** ?

Comment: Where are you blocked ? Have you noticed for example that the exponents could be $A,B,C$ instead of $1/a,1/b,1/c$ ... that there is a natural change of variable to try...

Comment: Why don't you answer ? A last attempt : have you tried particular values for the exponents: if c=1/2, b=1, a=1...$ what can you do ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I need the answer in terms of a, b and c.

Answer (score 3):

With the change of variables $t =  y^{1/c}$, your integral becomes

$$ J = c \int_0^1 (1 - (1-t)^{1/b})^{1/a} t^{c-1}\; dt$$

Expand $(1-(1-t)^{1/b})^{1/a}$ in binomial series, and interchange sum and integral:
$$ \eqalign{J &= c \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {1/a \choose k} \int_0^1  (1-t)^{k/b} t^{c-1}\; dt \cr
&= c \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k  {1/a \choose k} B(k/b+1, c)\cr
&= c \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\Gamma(1+1/a) \Gamma(c) \Gamma(1+k/b)}{\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(c+1+k/b) \Gamma(-k+1+1/a)}   }$$

I don't know if this can be done in "closed form" in general, but for small positive integers $a,b,c$ it seems to give rational numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am stuck again in another integration. $$
cb \int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^{1/a} (1-x^{b})^{c-1}$$ how can I solve it?